# How to reuse prefix on restricted qualified imports

Tags: haskell

I often find I'm using a library with a set of related modules, say:

```
A.B
A.B.C
A.B.D
```

I know I can do

```
import A.B (f1, f3)
import A.B.C (f7)
```

But sometimes these functions have common names that I don't want to pollute the main namespace with.

So I can do:

```
import qualified A.B (f1, f3) 
import qualified A.B.C (f7)
```

But then I have to call functions like `A.B.C.f7` which is quite long.

I could do:

```
import qualified A.B   as B 
import qualified A.B.C as C
```

Which helps a little bit, but I still have to remember and specify whether my functions are from B or C.

What I've found is that you can do this:

```
import qualified A.B   as B 
import qualified A.B.C as B
```

Except if there's a function in both `A.B` and `A.B.C` with the same name and you attempt to use it you'll get a compile error.

So what I basically want to do is this:

```
import qualified A.B (f1, f3) as B 
import qualified A.B.C (f7)   as B
```

But this won't compile. Is this possible (perhaps with an extension), and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Try instead

```
import qualified A.B   as B (f1, f3) 
import qualified A.B.C as B (f7)
```

This is possible without any extensions in GHC.